# Smaller Than Default Navbar Height Causing Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I like the look of a smaller-than-normal `navbar` height, as it seems to be a popular design trend.

However, this seems to be causing issues when opening a `collapse` menu.

Here you can see the stages of expanding the `collapse navbar-collapse` menu. First is my normal `navbar` with a minimum height of 30px. Then when I click the toggle button, the navbar briefly expands to what appears to be 50px, and finally the full screen menu appears.

[image: navbar height issue]

This alone isn't a big deal (though I would prefer a smooth transition), however the expand and collapse animations of the menu don't seem to behave as expected with a decreased `navbar` height.

Any ideas why this is happening? Or, is there something else in my styling that has nothing to do with the `navbar` height yet is causing the issue?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#main-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.article {
    flex: 1;
}

/*START Shrinks the default navbar height*/
.navbar {
  min-height: 30px;
  //max-height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
}

.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-nav > li > a:link,
.navbar-nav > li > a:visited {
  padding: 4px 5px 0px 5px;
  //height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 2px 8px 0 0;
}
/*END*/

.nav.navbar-nav li a:focus,
.nav.navbar-nav li a:active,
.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #444;
}

/*Displays navbar dropdown on hover */
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 22px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    margin: -4px 20px -3px 0;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/*Change hamburger menu to "x" on click */
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse { 
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none; 
}

/*Change Background color of toggle dropdown*/
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #444;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

h3 + p {
  line-height: 1.8em;
}


footer {
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer a,
footer a:link,
footer a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover,
footer a:active,
footer a:focus {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.tagline {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-sub {
  border: thin white solid;
  margin: 0 2px 7px 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fa-plus {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: right;
}

.fa-plus:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#location-detail {
  display: none;
}

a#location:focus + #location-detail {
  display: block;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav > li,
  .navbar-nav > li > a,
  .navbar-nav > li > a:link,
  .navbar-nav > li > a:visited,
  .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    font-size: 1.05em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px !important;
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-collapse li {
    display: none;
  }

  .collapse.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #444;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;

    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
  }

  .collapse.navbar-collapse li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

}


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

              <div class="container">

                   <div class="navbar-header">

                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">

                             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                             <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>                               
                             <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>

                        </button>

                        <!--<a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img class="logo" src="../images/eclipse-new.png"/></a> -->
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Eclipse Music</a>

                   </div> <!-- end of navbar-header -->

                   <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                         <!--<li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>-->
                          <li><a href="">Effects</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://www.eclipsemusic.org/guitars-basses-and-amps">Guitar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Bass</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Amps</a></li>

                          <li><a href="">Lessons</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown">

                               <a href="about/about.php">About<!--&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>--></a>

                               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                     <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                               </ul>

                          </li>

                         </ul>

                   </div> <!-- end of collapse navbar-collapse -->

              </div> <!-- end of container -->

         </div> <!-- end of navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top -->
```

[Here is my site in progress](https://www.twincataudio.com/eclipse/eclipse.html). I tried copying the styling and markup to JS Fiddle, but it wasn't matching what my webpage shows.

Comment: Can you give us the live example or put together a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, let me try. I've been having some difficulty in JS Fiddle though. Even including external resources for Bootstrap, it's still leaving out some styling.

Comment: [Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/446jp8o5/1/) I'd update my question to include it, but as you can see it looks incomplete. Added link to my site in progress to my question.

Comment: Neither your website nor fiddle look like the screenshots...

Comment: Sorry, I had added an image and one more list item to the site. I've removed the image for now, but the staggered transition still remains the same. As far as the JS Fiddle, I am having issues with that. I don't know why it doesn't look like my site; I used the JS Fiddle Bootstrap template.